# Count two duplicate and other unique value in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iteration

I have a multidimensional array set of 10 and i want to fetch 4 records from this array but first 2 records should have same dealer_id + other 2 are unique and may be same. But first 2 should have same dealer_id .if there is no duplicate records in array then  all 4 records are distinct. so any idea about what would be the fastest and most efficient way to do this.

```
$array = array(array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 2)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 3)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 2)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 5)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 7)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 9)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 8)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 10)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 12)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 3)),
    array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 12)));
```

I will try this.

```
$arr2 = array();
$counter = 0;
for ($arr = 0; $arr < count($array); $arr++) {

    if (in_array($array[$arr], $arr2)) {
        ++$counter;
        continue;
    } else {
        $arr2[] = $array[$arr];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr2);die;
```

Comment: Post your expected array.

Comment: @RaviHirani They are separate arrays

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Ohh!! My mistake. You are correct. I have edited my earlier comment.

Comment: expected result like : array(array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 2)), array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 2)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 3)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 5)));

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the array while keeping track of which `dealer_id` you've already seen in an array indexed by the `dealer_id`. As soon as you get the 1st duplicate, break out of the iteration and get 2 more rows (or 4 if there were no duplicates).

```
$indexed_array = [];
$results = [];

foreach ($array as $e) {
    if (!isset($indexed_array[$e['_source']['dealer_id']])) {
        $indexed_array[$e['_source']['dealer_id']] = $e;
    }
    else {
        // add the 2 results with the same dealer_id to your results
        $results[] = $indexed_array[$e['_source']['dealer_id']];
        $results[] = $e;
        break;
    }
}


if (!empty($results)) {
    // get 2 more elements with a different dealer_id
    foreach ($array as $e) {
       if ($e['_source']['dealer_id'] != $results[0]['_source']['dealer_id']) {
          $results[] = $e;
          if (count($results) > 3) {
             break;
          }
       }
    }
}
else {
    // there are no duplicates so just get the 1st 4 elements
    $results = array_slice($array, 0, 4);
}

print_r($results);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/deftYg)

Comment: array(array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 4)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 3)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 2)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 5)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 7)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 9)),
array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 8)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 10)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 12)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 3)),array("_source" => array("dealer_id" => 12))); it won't work with this array why dealer_id 3 will come more than 2 .